# what shall I write that my application didn't change orientation in case of phone turn?

Tags: android, orientation

what shall I write that my application didn't change orientation in case of phone turn for an angle of ninety degrees?

Comment: Do you want your activity to always be in 1 kind of orientation?

Comment: yes. i want my activity to always be in 1 kind of orientation. I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your AndroidManifest.xml file, you can specify the default screen orientation for each of your application's activities. Use `android:screenOrientation` tag with a value such as `portrait` or `landscape`. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use screenOrientation tag in your activity declaration in manifest. You can set landscap or portrait depending on your requirement. Below is an example...
 '
'

```
 <activity android:name=".ActivityName"

              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```